# Saving an entire Bundle to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, bundle, sharedpreferences

Assuming a method of mine was passed a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) already filled with data to be saved, is there a way to save it to [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) **without taking it apart** to ints, floats, Strings, etc.?

I prefer the convenience of writing/committing it all in "one fell swoop", so if this isn't possible using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html), what other [persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404348/869501) storage approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as far as I know, you can save only primitive data (and their wrappers) to SharedPreferences

why don't you create your own helper method which will iterate through Bundle and save all values from it to SharedPreferences?

Comment: SharedPreferences is meant to store simple types, but I suppose you could serialize your Bundle into a byte array and cast it to a string.

One might argue that you are only displacing the effort of maintaining your SharedPreferences to the effort of maintaining a Bundle.

Comment: My approach is to prefer methods and techniques that already exist in the framework instead of "re-inventing the wheel". My question was aimed at finding out whether such helper method already exists in the Android SDK or I should indeed create my own. I think you answered my question. +1.

Comment: @Sparky *"One might argue that you are **only displacing the effort** of maintaining your SharedPreferences to the effort of maintaining a Bundle."* - I very much identify with this but examining the possibility of using `Bundle.writeToParcel()`, then serializing it to a `String`, looks way more generic & efficient than having to update the helper method every time a new state variable is added.

Comment: @Sparky Then again, [Parcel.marshall()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#marshall%28%29) documentation warns that *"The data you retrieve here must not be placed in any kind of persistent storage (on local disk, across a network, etc)."*. Which makes the task of generalizing the saving of any Bundle to local Android persistent storage daunting... (I was only looking for a 5-minute solution, not a 5-hours one).

Answer (score 16):

SharedPreferences are serialized to XML, which is why you can only use simple types. You'll either have to do your own conversion of the bundle to individual SharePreferences properties or serialize the bundle some other way to disk.

Here's a good reference document discussing the various possibilities of storing data in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: +1 for explaining the reason *why* SharedPreferences only support simple types.

Answer (score 0):

- Note: **If you are using Gson in your project then I think this is a better solution.**

I simply used `Gson` from `Google` to serialize the specified object into its equivalent JSON representation:

> Use this dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

> Code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String dataToJson = gson.toJson(modelObj);
```

*Then I stored `dataToJson` as a string in SharedPreferences.Simple!*

> At the time of string extraction:

```
String myStoredVal = Value stored in SharedPreference. 
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setPrettyPrinting();

Gson gson = builder.create();
MyModel modelObj = gson.fromJson(prodDataStr, MyModel.class);
```