# Saving Bundle object into shared preference

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, bundle

I have 2 Activities

Activity1

Activity2

**Activity1:**

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Activity1.this,Acivity2.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();      
b.putParcelableArrayList("actionArray", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) AllListArray.get(0)); 
b.putParcelableArrayList("comedyArray", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) AllListArray.get(1));
b.putParcelableArrayList("loveArray", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) AllListArray.get(2));
b.putParcelableArrayList("classicsArray", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) AllListArray.get(3));
b.putParcelableArrayList("familyArray", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) AllListArray.get(4));

intent.putExtras(b);             
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity2:**

Activity2:

```
 public List<Movie> actionArray;
     public List<Movie> comedyArray;
     public List<Movie> loveArray;
     public List<Movie> classicsArray;
     public List<Movie> familyArray;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(recdData!=null) {
            actionArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("actionArray");
            comedyArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("comedyArray");
            loveArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("loveArray");
            classicsArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("classicsArray");
            familyArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("familyArray");
        }
    }
```

My Requirement is to Store the `Bundle(recdData)` into `Sharedpreferences` in Activity2?
Could any one help me?

Comment: first at least search your problem on google u will get the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660889/save-bundle-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903718/saving-an-entire-bundle-to-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1):

in your Activity2

```
public void addTask(Task t) {
    if (null == currentTasks) {
        currentTasks = new ArrayList<task>();
    }
    currentTasks.add(t);

    //save the task list to preference
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    try {
        editor.putString(TASKS, ObjectSerializer.serialize(currentTasks));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Similarly we have to retrieve the list of tasks from the preference in the onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (null == currentTasks) {
        currentTasks = new ArrayList<task>();
    }

    //      load tasks from preference
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    try {
        currentTasks = (ArrayList<task>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(TASKS, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<task>())));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can get ObjectSerializer class from Apache Pig project ObjectSerializer.java

Comment: Sorry,i'm not clear about answer,Could you describe?

Answer (score 1):

```
preferences = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(
                    SharePreference_demo, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 



 Map<String, String> demoarraylist= new HashMap<String, String>();
    demoarraylist.put("actionArray", "action");
    demoarraylist.put("comedyArray", "comedy");
    demoarraylist.put("lovearray", "love");
    demoarraylist.put("classicArray", "classic");
    demoarraylist.put("familyArray", "family");



SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : demoarraylist.entrySet()) {
                    editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
             editor.commit();
```

put above code put in your 1st activity.

and below code is put in your 2nd activity.

```
 Map<String, String> demoarraylist= new HashMap<String, String>();


 SharedPreferences preferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(
                    SharePreference_demo, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            for (Entry<String, ?> entry : preferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
                demoarraylist.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
            }


Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = demoarraylist.keySet().iterator();
        while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            String value = (String) MapListUserStatus.get(key);
}
```

Comment: My ArrayList is CustomObject ArraList,see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> MapListUserStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : MapListUserStatus.entrySet()) {
                    editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
```

Store your ArrayListData into sharedprefernces using HashMap().

Retrieve sharedPreferences data:

```
MapListUserStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();




 SharedPreferences preferences = conductpd.getSharedPreferences(
                    SharePreference_messages_history, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            for (Entry<String, ?> entry : preferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
                MapListUserStatus.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
            }
```

I hope its useful to you..if any query.please tell me.

Comment: Sorry,i'm new to programming ,According to my question could you edit your answer?

Comment: @dipali post your edit in the previous answer