# How to Save and retrieve Custom Arrailist from Shared Preference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I want to Store and retrieve my Custom object Arralist from Sharedpreference,i have tried but getting Compiletime Error

Could any one help?

Code:

```
 @Override protected void onPause() {
    List<Movie> movieList;
            super.onPause();        


                //save the movie list to preference
                SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);           
                Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                try {
                    editor.putString("movies", org.apache.pig.impl.util.ObjectSerializer.serialize(movieList));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                editor.commit();
            }
}
```

Here is the Model class which is to be :

```
 public class Movie implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String MovieName;
        private String MovieActor;
        private String MovieActress;
        private String MovieDirector;
        private String MovieImage;
        private String MovieDescription;
        private String MovieWatchLink;
        public String getMovieName() {
            return MovieName;
        }
        public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
            MovieName = movieName;
        }
        public String getMovieActor() {
            return MovieActor;
        }
        public void setMovieActor(String movieActor) {
            MovieActor = movieActor;
        }
        public String getMovieActress() {
            return MovieActress;
        }
        public void setMovieActress(String movieActress) {
            MovieActress = movieActress;
        }
        public String getMovieDirector() {
            return MovieDirector;
        }
        public void setMovieDirector(String movieDirector) {
            MovieDirector = movieDirector;
        }
        public String getMovieImage() {
            return MovieImage;
        }
        public void setMovieImage(String movieImage) {
            MovieImage = movieImage;
        }
        public String getMovieDescription() {
            return MovieDescription;
        }
        public void setMovieDescription(String movieDescription) {
            MovieDescription = movieDescription;
        }
        public String getMovieWatchLink() {
            return MovieWatchLink;
        }
        public void setMovieWatchLink(String movieWatchLink) {
            MovieWatchLink = movieWatchLink;
        }
```

**Compile time Error:**

```
The method serialize(Serializable) in the type ObjectSerializer is not applicable for the 
arguments (List<Movie>)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Bundle object into shared preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821405/saving-bundle-object-into-shared-preference)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the SharedPreference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `List<Movie> movieList;` use `ArrayList<Movie> movieList`;

Answer (score 2):

List<> does not implement the Serializable interface. (Movie does).
You could try ArrayList (cannot try it out here)

Comment: The error state that it is a compiler error not a run time error.

Comment: you can try `ArrayList` instead of `List` interface.

Comment: @Sunny, indeed missed the part that is was compile time.